Random slopes vs including an interaction between grouping factor and focal predictor
A person runs the following random slopes model where ses is the focal predictor, and schcode is the grouping factor (and so not mentioned in the model equation)
$Y_{ij} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}\text{ses_mean}_{0j} + \gamma_{02}\text{pro4yrc}_{0j} + \gamma_{03}\text{public}_{0j} + \gamma_{10}\text{ses}_{ij} + u_{0j} + u_{1j}\text{ses}_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}$
They then contemplate the idea of removing the random slopes and instead having an interaction between the grouping factor schcode and the focal predictor ses. The random intercept for schcode would still be kept. Thus the model would look like the following:
$Y_{ij} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}\text{ses_mean}_{0j} + \gamma_{02}\text{pro4yrc}_{0j} + \gamma_{03}\text{public}_{0j} + \gamma_{04}\text{schcode}_{0j} + \gamma_{10}\text{ses}_{ij} + \gamma_{14}\text{ses}_{ij} \times \text{schcode}_{0j} + u_{0j} + \epsilon_{ij}$
Somehow this second model seems strange to me because schcode is part of both the random and fixed structure, but there is at least one response on this site in which a very authoritative source advised that this can be OK (albeit in a scenario quite different from the one being considered here).
Is this second model sensible at all, and why/why not? What are the pros and cons of it versus the first model?
I am more concerned about general principles here than the specific data set, but I am also interested in what makes sense with regard to this specific data set.
Code for the example is here:
library(haven)
library(lme4)

d <- read_sav(file ="https://github.com/user1205901/codeforposting/blob/main/ch3multilevel.sav?raw=true")

model1 <- lmer(math ~ 1 + ses + ses_mean + pro4yrc + public + (ses||schcode), data = d)
summary(model1)

model2 <- lmer(math ~ 1 + ses_mean + pro4yrc + public + ses + ses*schcode + (1|schcode), data = d)
summary(model2)


I am not one for explaining the theory, but I will say that it is often the case that an effect is part of both the random and fixed structures. I don't have a specific example, but I've seen it many times and it is in some of the examples in SAS PROC MIXED and so on.   If you don't get a good answer, you might want to browse the SAS documentation.

I am very familiar with multilevel modeling in education and psychology. It is exceedingly rare to see models that have both a random (varying) intercept for a factor and a fixed (non-varying) intercept for the same factor. While you can estimate that in a model, given enough data, it is not at all clear what you gain.
Most analysts choose one or the other approach. Economists who work with panel data prefer the fixed (non-varying) intercepts because they worry about level 2 endogeneity. They do not, however, include both random and fixed intercepts in their models. Most other fields I am aware of prefer the random (varying) intercepts. An exception is when there are a very small number of groups (say <=5), in which case, most would simply include indicators for the groups.
Please note that you need to amend your code for model2 to properly account for the fact that school is a factor variable. Probably because of the data being from SPSS, lmer() is treating it as a continuous variable, and the results you get do not accurately represent the data. When you change it to the following, you can begin to see how strange this approach is:
model2 <- lmer(math ~ 1 + ses_mean + pro4yrc + public + ses + ses*as.factor(schcode) + (1|schcode), data = d)

You get an error message that fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients and then you proceed to get nearly 850 coefficients, 1/2 comprising the fixed intercepts for each school and then half the ses*school interaction. This is a hugely inefficient model that can be reduced significantly by slightly amending your model1:
# ses|schcode allows for a covariance between the slopes and intercepts
model3 <- lmer(math ~ 1 + ses + ses_mean + pro4yrc + public + (ses|schcode), data = d) 

This model allows for varying intercepts for each school and allows the ses slope to vary by school. It summarizes this variation in three parameters - variances associated with the intercept and slope and then a covariance between them. In total, the model has just 9 parameter estimates (vs 841). As compared to model2, the AIC and BIC, which are measures of model fit that are about predicting new data, hugely favor the more parsimonious model. The Chi-square test of the two models favors the less parsimonious model, but I have never seen a published analysis of a model with that structure. It is hugely inefficient and unnecessary.
